# Как сделать секундомер, который будет запускаться с нуля при запуске функции или если есть возможность, то узнать точное время создания функции

Tags: php

У меня есть функция, которая запускается когда человек что-то определенное сделает, и нужно чтобы с того момента как вызвалась функция, чтобы ровно через 35 дней что-то происходило. Можно ли как-то проверять когда была создана функция? Ну или же как сделать секундомер, который запустится как только запустится функция?

Comment: так создана функция или запустилась? 35 дней достаточно большой срок, обычно в пхп одна функция сколько не работает, поэтому сохраняйте в базу, а потом время от времени проверяйте ее и выполняйте то, чему пришло время. Крон в помощь

Comment: cron запускается каждое утро и смотрит логи(складывайте в файлик csv) проверяя их дата + 35 дней, и если находит совпадение запускает то что нужно